# CodeDom Provider could not be located on IIS7

Tags: iis

I have added a site on my IIS but when I try to get to the default page, I get the following error :

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.

Source Error: 


Line 12:   <system.codedom>
Line 13:     <compilers>
Line 14:       <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
Line 15:       <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
Line 16:     </compilers>
```

Do I need to install the "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" package with nuget to make it works or is it something different ?

Answer (score 8):

You can comment out the entire System.CodeDom section from web.config. 
WebApplication projects will have the CodeDom section, WebSite projects wont. Comment it out and it should start working.

Source:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1034471/Unable-to-run-ASP-net-pages-on-web-server

Answer (score 5):

Try running inetmgr (IIS) right click your website and Choose Convert to Application.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe do you have different version compiler? Try - **Project > Manage NuGet Packages... > Browse(tab) >** in search input set this:
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

You can install or update or uninstall and install this compiler

[image: DotNetCompilerPlatform]

Answer (score 4):

I solved similar issue by installing updates TOOLS->NuGetPackage Installer  MENU -> ALL-> Update especially for Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to Bayak, you have settings in WebConfig that are not compatible for your web server. Visual Studio can add alot of extra weight to the file by default. Trim WebConfig to:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```